# Check if a number is prime Using powershell

Tags: powershell, primes

This is my script to check if a random number is prime or not :

```
[int]$nombre = Get-Random -Minimum 1 -Maximum 10
$nombre
$j=0

if($nombre -lt 2) { " $nombre n'est pas premier " }

else {

for($i=1; $i -le $nombre; $i++){

if( $nombre%$i -eq 0) {$j++}

 }
 if($j -eq 2 ) { "Le nombre est  premier "}
 else {"Ce nombre est premier"}
   }
```

When I execute the script I get wrong results like 4 is a prime number. Any ideas to fixe it ?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just wanted to improve the existing answer.

To me it is so obvious that I don't understand why hasn't anyone pointed out, it could simplify the whole process by skipping the for loop if the number is a square number, just add `if ([math]::Sqrt{$number} -is [int]) {$prime = $false}` to the code before the loop, by definition square numbers are composite numbers, why no one noticed it?

Update: a better function based on the previous answer, it assigns $false to negative numbers, zero and fractions and non-numbers:

```
function Test-Prime {
    param(
    [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
    $number
    )
    
   Process {
    $prime = $true;
    if ($number -isnot [int]) {$prime = $false}
    elseif ($number -le 0) {$prime = $false}
    else {
        if ($number -eq 1) {
            $prime = $false;
        }
        if ($number -gt 3) {
            $sqrt = [math]::Sqrt($number); 
            if ($sqrt -is [int]) {$prime = $false}
            else {
                for($i = 2; $i -le $sqrt; $i++) {
                    if ($number % $i -eq 0) {
                        $prime = $false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return $prime;
}
```

}

Comment: By definition, one and zero are not prime numbers, prime numbers are postive integers that have exactly two factors (one and themselves), so negative numbers and fraction/decimals are not prime numbers, and prime numbers have to be, well, numbers, this improved algorithm will produce meaningful result to anything inputed and will not produce exceptions...

Comment: I dont think you can depend on type to detect whole numbers.

For me in pwsh core 7.4 i get the following

    `> ([math]::pow(2,2)-1) -isnot [int]`
    `True`
    `> 3 -isnot [int]`
    `False`

Answer (score 0):

You need to start your for loop at 3, not 1. everything is evenly divisible by 1, you already tested for division by 2.

There are multiple things wrong with your code. The j counter is one of them. Looping including $nombre is also one.

```
function Test-Prime {
    param(
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
        [int]$number
        )

    Process {
        $prime = $true;

        if ($number -eq 1) {
            $prime = $false;
        }
        if ($number -gt 3) {
            # limit loop to max sqrt($number)
            $sqrt = [math]::Sqrt($number); 
            for($i = 2; $i -le $sqrt; $i++) {
                if ($number % $i -eq 0) {
                    # we found it is not prime
                    $prime = $false;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        return $prime;
    }
}

# test for all values between 1 and 100
1..10 | %{ Write-Host " $_ $( Test-Prime $_)" }
```

Which prints

> 1 False
>   2 True
>   3 True
>   4 False
>   5 True
>   6 False
>   7 True
>   8 False
>   9 False
>   10 False

Comment: Why not add square root instead of just making a comment. It takes the same amount of time for you. :) Also, you should replace `-lt $number - 1` with `-lt $number`.  Here's the square root modification: `$sqrt = [int]([math]::Sqrt($number)); for($i = 2; $i -le $sqrt; $i++) { ...`

Comment: @FrodeF. it should be `$i -lt $sqrt` unless it misses squared numbers (9 etc..).

Comment: @oɔɯǝɹ Yeah, it was a typo when I edited in the cast to int. Used an old sample in ISE. :)

Comment: Thank you. Just one thing, 1 is not prime

Comment: @Souad I updated to deal with 1. There are many other edge cases still here though. Like `0`, or negative numbers, or `$null`, or anything else really. Don't use this code for anything!

Answer (score 0):

Here is another code-snippet for you. It shows you the first primes up to 1000.

```
cls
$primelist = [System.Collections.ArrayList]::new()
foreach($number in 0..1000) {
    if ($number -le 3) {
        $isprime = $number -gt 1
        $maxDiv  = 2
    } else {
        $isprime = $true
        foreach($div in $primeList) {
            if ($number % $div -eq 0) {
                $isprime = $false
                if ($maxDiv*$maxDiv -lt $number){$maxDiv++}
                break
            }
            if ($div -ge $maxDiv) {break}
        }
    }
    if ($isprime) {[void]$primelist.Add($number)}
}
write-host ([string]::Join(',',$primeList.ToArray()))
```

For larger prime numbers I recommend using the Rabin-Miller function. Details see here: [How to generate a large prime via cryptography provider?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75285135/how-to-generate-a-large-prime-via-cryprography-provider/75286796#75286796)

Answer (score 0):

```
1..2000|?{('1'*$_) -notmatch '^1?$|^(11+?)\1+$'}
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**